Is there a maximum number of languages per site?
Is there a maximum number of languages for a website before considering going into a multisite ?
Thank you,

There will be a theoretical maximum, but that number would be much higher than the total number of languages in existence. So no, there is no realistic maximum. The part about multisites isn't relevant - a multisite is multiple different sites based on a single shared codebase, it doesn't represent translations. Indeed any site in a multisite can have multiple languages.
